# Expansion of action in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, action

I am reading a lot about GR lately (because of thesis), and one thing bothers me, and I'm not finding a direct answer to it. For instance in one article, the author says that they are expanding Einstein-Hilbert action, that is, they have Einstein-Hilbert action of this form:

$$S=\int_{\partial M}d^nx\sqrt{-g}(R-2\Lambda)$$

(no matter field, just cosmological constant), and that by putting $g_{\mu\nu}\to g_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$, where $h_{\mu\nu}=\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\mu\nu}$ in action, we can expand it to what ever order we want.

Now, does this mean, that I'm just making variations, first once of the action, then variation of that variation etc ($\delta S,\ \delta^2S,\ \ldots$), and that this is 'expanding' this action?

I guess my confusion comes from the fact that I think of expansion in terms of Taylor series.

Can anybody point me in right direction?

Comment: Please give the reference to the article.

Comment: You might want to look into the Killing vector some: http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~rajeev/phy413/Grav18.pdf

Comment: The author might be referring to expanding the integrand in powers of $h$ which is being viewed as a perturbation to $g$.

Comment: @Ben Crowell: it is this article: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.1031.pdf
Are there different methods of expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by joshphysics, the formula $(9)$ is referring to a Taylor serie in powers of the metrics perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$:

$S = S^0[h] + S^1[h] + S^2[h] + ...+S^n[h] ...$

Each term $S^n[h]$ has a $n$-power dependence on the $h_{\mu\nu}$

Here $h_{\mu\nu}=\nabla_\mu \xi_\nu+\nabla_\nu \xi_\mu$

So, the Taylor expansion is a expansion in powers of $\xi_\mu$

For instance, the $S^1[\xi]$ action term (formula $10$) is linear in the $\xi_\mu$, while the $S^2[\xi]$ action term (formula $12$) is quadratic in the  $\xi_\mu$.

Comment: So it really is just Taylor expansion? Wow. Often I stumble upon expansion in articles about GR, and not of this type, is this something different, like perturbation or? I mean, are there some special expansion formula in GR or is it all just Taylor? Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @dingo_d: If you may identify a small parameter or a family of small parameters (relatively to 1)  , you are always able to make a Taylor expansion, in powers of these small parameters. So, depending on the problem, or/and depending on the theory, a lot of expansions are possible.

Comment: Well, to be accurate, it's a [von Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) expansion of the inverse of the metric, which is used when computing the Ricci scalar. Typically, you truncate the series at some point...